# Why Record type in TS with undefined as a value should have strictly defined fields?

Tags: typescript

Practically my question is related to a situation below:

I have a type for form values

```js
interface FormValues {
  name: string
  description: string
  expirationDate: Date | null
}
```

and a type for errors that can be created if there are errors in a form

```js
const errors: Record<keyof FormValues, string | undefined> = {
    name: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    expirationDate: undefined
}
```

however, the errors type works only if I define each fields as undefined, if I try to change it to an empty object, then TS responses with an error

```js
const errors: Record<keyof FormValues, string | undefined> = {}
/*
Type '{}' is missing the following properties 
from type 'Record<keyof FormValues, string | undefined>': name, description, expirationDate
*/
```

how to change the error type to reflect my need in having an object with the fields defined as a string or non-exist:

```js
const validate = values => {
  const errors: ??? = {}
  if (!values.name) errors.name = 'Required'
  if (!values.description) errors.description = 'Required'
  if (!values.expirationDate) errors.expirationDate = 'Required'
  return errors
}
```

Comment: your error type looks like FormikErrors. And your validate looks like a yup or zod validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type utility [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to make the keys of a type optional:

```ts
const errors: Partial<Record<keyof FormValues, string>> = {};
```

Here's a complete example based on the code from your question:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=52#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsBqcA2ArhAM7IDeAUMsiHFhAFzIlhSgDmA3NcgCakE7AA5hg6EM1bsQ3XhAAew4FDhiJAETVNkWyMgA+tQvnw8AvpUoIJrZDEy4CxANIQAnmQC8yANq8AIjoGAIAaQIESIWBRcRAwwMVlVXUQPQgEgF1kODIbEDsSNWASGGBSZCgIOD4JfHdkAAoAaw90GDRHPCJSAEpfTJ5rWzBkADcCYD5tZB9GiZ6SZgxsbuISXtmAPgpefLtoKEwl5AAFOCgxAgAeACUIGyg+a9b3ds7V51JQljZOLZ2PnI5iGNAcUCa+1Gr2Q73BTh6bk8myoNBowA6jQAhAt1r5XplNodjviPNkfAF7gBHQgqCB8AI8GiWXhVMCEKAgZDEqAkCw8IA)

```ts
const formValueKeys = [
  "name",
  "description",
  "expirationDate",
] as const satisfies readonly (keyof FormValues)[];

const validate = (values: FormValues) => {
  const errors: Partial<Record<keyof FormValues, string>> = {};

  for (const key of formValueKeys) {
    if (!values[key]) errors[key] = "Required";
  }

  return errors;
};
```

Comment: Return type should not be `Partial` because all the keys have been defined.

Comment: warning, if form value gets a new key, like firstname:string, you also have to add a new key in formValueKeys.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75387390/why-record-type-in-ts-with-undefined-as-a-value-should-have-strictly-defined-fie/75387560?noredirect=1#comment133020812_75387560) @vera. Do you mean the not-annotated return type of the `validate` function? Can you clarify your meaning — why do you think it shouldn't be partial?

Comment: My bad, I was misreading the piece of code... There is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this (your type) :

```
type errorType1 = Record<keyof FormValues, string | undefined>
```

wich is equivalent to

```
type errorType1 = {
    name: string | undefined;
    description: string | undefined;
    expirationDate: string | undefined;
}
```

Then look at

```
type errorType2 = Partial<Record<keyof FormValues, string>>
```

which is equivalent to

```
type errorType2 = {
    name?: string | undefined;
    description?: string | undefined;
    expirationDate?: string | undefined;
}
```

With error type 2, you are allowed to forget keys. With the first you can't.

What you need is probably  :

```
const errors: Partial<Record<keyof FormValues, string>> = {}
```